# Python: aggregate not unique value lists into a dictionary for csv output

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I need to export the content of 8 lists to a csv file (Google Cal export)

```
# Class dates (there can be the same value for several iterations)
datefield = []

# All fields are linked to a date (same index)
starttimefield = []
endtimefield = []
subjectfield = []
typefield = []
teacherfield = []
groupfield = []
roomfield = []
```

What I am looking for is such csv output on every row (for every date in datefield):

```
subjectfield,datefield,starttimefield,datefield,endtimefield,FALSE,typefield,roomfield
```

So far, I've tried this (somehow it does not want to write if using `'wb'` mode):

```
rows = subjectfield,datefield,starttimefield,datefield,endtimefield,FALSE,typefield,roomfield
zip(*rows)

with open('classes.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile, fieldnames=['Subject', 'Start Date', 'Start Time', 'End Date', 'End Time', 'All Day Event', 'Description', 'Location', 'Private']
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem is that I get a csv file like this (one row for every list value):

```
subjectfield[0]
subjectfield[1]
subjectfield[...]
datefield[0]
datefield[1]
...
```

I understand that csv.DictWriter().writerow only accept dictionaries, and I have no clue how to aggregate lists into a dictionary the way I need it; datefield may contain the same value several times as there can be multiples classes the same day.

Therefore, what I am looking for would be something like this:

```
with open('classes.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile, fieldnames=['Subject', 'Start Date', 'Start Time', 'End Date', 'End Time', 'All Day Event', 'Description', 'Location', 'Private']
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(len(datefield)):
        writer.writerow(subjectfield[i], datefield[i], starttimefield[i], datefield[i], endtimefield[i], "FALSE", typefield[i], roomfield[i])
```

Comment: check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It is useful for data analysis, data manipulation and It supports excel csv txt output.

Comment: break you problems into smaller ones.. If you don't have a dict, why use `csv.Dictwriter()`? Or if you do want to use `Dictwriter` for some reason just focus on creating the dict to begin with. You are making your life complicated by stacking errors on top of each other.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how to write rows without dictionaries, DictWriter.writerow requires a dictionary ; I am looking for a way to pass directly values for each field to the writerow function
Btw, it seems hard to make a single dictionary in my program because I need multiples values for dates (key) which have several classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using pandas (I did not manage to make the latest answer work):

```
raw_data = {'Subject': subjectfield,
            'Start Date': datefield,
            'Start Time': starttimefield,
            'End Date': datefield,
            'End Time': endtimefield,
            'All Day Event': 'False',
            'Description': '',
            'Location': roomfield}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Subject', 'Start Date', 'Start Time', 'End Date', 'End Time', 'All Day Event',
                                     'Description', 'Location'])
df.to_csv("classes_schedule.csv", sep=",", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty straight forward in a library called pandas.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
write_data = DataFrame([])

# DataFrame.insert(#position,'ColumnName',Value)
write_data.insert(0,'subjectfield',pd.DataFrame(subjectfield))
write_data.insert(1,'datefield',pd.DataFrame(datefield))
write_data.insert(2,'starttimefield',pd.DataFrame(starttimefield))
write_data.insert(3,'endtimefield',pd.DataFrame(endtimefield))
write_data.insert(4,'boolean',False)
write_data.insert(5,'typefield',pd.DataFrame(typefield))
write_data.insert(6,'roomfield',pd.DataFrame(roomfield))

#DataFrame.to_csv('File_name',sep='SEPERATOR') 
write_data.to_csv('my_file.csv',sep=',')
```

I'm not sure whether you wanted a Column with the name 'FALSE' or the column to have only False values so I did the latter. I'm also not sure if the additional 'datefield' column was intentional - no two columns as far as I understand can be present in a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, though it raised the following exception:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 389, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = values
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (87,1) into shape (87)`